# c# BitcoinLib: GetRawTransaction verbose=1 does not work

Tags: api, json-rpc, c#, .net

I want to find out confirmation number for non-wallet transaction.

When I use 
`CoinService.DecodeRawTransaction(CoinService.GetRawTransaction("5bc89f4e7f7fe4bd6bd15b439038e2a50a88c158680814164d3428a73a84daef"))` I got transaction details, but without confirmations field.

I assume I should use `GetRawTransaction("..", 1)` but got exception "There was a problem deserializing the response from the wallet".

Answer (score 1):

RPC `decoderawtransaction` doesn't return a `confirmations` field so yes, you should use `getrawtransaction` in its `verbose` mode instead.

I called [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib)'s `GetRawTransaction` for the tx in question and I got a proper response, as expected:

[image]

Please make sure you have [BitcoinLib's latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitcoinLib/) and that your wallet is synched and [indexed](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib#instructions-for-bitcoin).